# submenu doesn't slides up on mouseleave of main menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When I mouseout of submenu then it slides up but if I mouseout from main menu without focusing on submenu then it wont.
Here is my code

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.sublinks').stop(false, true).hide();
    var submenu = $(this).parent().next();
    submenu.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px',
        left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
        zIndex: 1
    });
    submenu.stop(true,
    true).slideDown(300);
    submenu.mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

---

HTML-

```
<ul id ="ul1" >
        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown"></a></li>

        <li class="sublinks">
            <table cellpadding ="0" cellspacing ="0">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="Product1.aspx">Product 1
                </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="Product2.aspx">Product 2</a></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="Product3.aspx">Product 3</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="Product4.aspx">Product 4</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="Product5.aspx">Product 5</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="Product6.aspx">Product 6</a></td>
            </tr>


            </table>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any online version of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work because `mouseleave` is bound to `sublinks`. And it will not happen because mouse never enter `sublinks`. You can fix this with `mouseleave` bound to both `sublinks` and `dropdown` (in case of `dropdown` handler you also will need to check if mouse does not enter `sublinks`). But that is not the best approach, as for me.

Suppose it would be better to put both `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` on `ul1`. As both `dropdown` and `sublinks` are children of `ul1`, `mouseleave` event will work correctly.